# Ubuntu 14.10 not available through software updater?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, 14.10

I'm in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I've enabled the "notify me for every new release" option. I still am not able to upgrade through software updater.

Comment: 14.10 is expected to be released today, but it is not out yet. You can't expect to be notified about a release that hasn't happened yet, surely?

Comment: Well, I think it is available, but not officially. You can get it through torrents right now.

Comment: It is my understanding that Canonical pushes out software updates in batches. That is, the "New upgrade available" notification does not pop up in every computer in the world with Ubuntu the instant the new version is released. You may have to wait a few days for it to come to you.

Comment: You've answered your own question then. If it's not available officially, then why do you expect it to be available via the official upgrade tool?

Comment: Yeah. I guess I was hoping someone would know about what time it would be available or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check again ;)**

It is now (@~18:30 UTC 2014) [officially released](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2014-October/000191.html).

---

Utopic Unicorn has not been released *yet*.

Wait a couple of minutes, check out [the website](http://ubuntu.com), stay awake because it's close to happen!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.10 "Utopic Unicorn" hasn't been released. Check this [website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) until it updates then download it. So excited :P

EDIT: It's released!! Check under Ubuntu 14.04 on that website :P

Answer (score 0):

You should install all the updates for your current release from the **Update Center**, then it will promote about the new release.

Answer (score -1):

If it still doesn't show up go to 'Settings' and under 'Software & Updates' click the 'Updates' tab and for 'Notify me of a new Ubuntu version'' make sure it's set to 'For any new version', click ok and check for updates and it should be there.